# Assigning to object doesn't work

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, async-await, nightwatch.js, object-property

I'm using **Nightwatch.js** and recently I spotted an interesting behaviour of the code.

I was trying to replace callback structures with ***async/await*** commands from JS6.

### Initially

Initially I started with this code. It checks if we have 2 tabs in the browser window.

```
# main.js

client.windowHandles((result) => {
    client.verify.equal(result.value.length, 2);
});
```

### Working code

And I replaced it with:

```
# main.js

const { assignVariable } = require("../../utils/callbacks");

let windows = {};

await client.windowHandles(assignVariable(windows));
client.verify.equal(windows.value.length, 2);
```

Where *assignVariable* is:

```
# callbacks.js

const assignVariable = (variable) => {
    return (result) => {
        variable.value = result.value;
    };
};

module.exports = { assignVariable };
```

And this code works.

### Not working code

Strange things are happening when I want to change *assignVariable* to:

```
# callbacks.js

const assignVariable = (variable) => {
    return (result) => {
        variable = result;
    };
};

module.exports = { assignVariable };
```

### Problem

Then ***assingVariable*** seems to **doesn't have an impact at all**.
I was debugging this lines and the assignment in *assignVariable* is executed but the object *windows* still equals *{}* when we are back in *main.js*.

I hope I've explained it clearly.

P.S. This is my 1st question in StackOverflow, so be patient with me. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first one works because you're *mutating an object* that you have a shared reference to. The second one (`variable = result`) merely assigns a value to a local variable. There's no connection to the `windows` variable in the caller's scope. Remember: when passing a variable to a function, you're passing only *the value*, not a reference to that variable.

Comment: Yes, you're right. I see now it's a common question in StackOverflow.
I was browsing the net and found detailed explanation here:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6605640/javascript-by-reference-vs-by-value